# Burninate the [drone] and [small-drones] tags

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, tags

Inspired from:

- [What should we do about the [small-drones] tag?](https://drones.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95/what-should-we-do-about-the-small-drones-tag)

In my opinion, we don't need these tags, the reasons why they are being used now:

- The question is very low quality
- This is the first tag the asker could find
- A tag did not exist for the asker's question

These tags are incredibly broad and should be burninated before the start of the public beta ([most likely on 28th April](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54175220#54175220)) to avoid mass-retagging afterwards.

**Suggested burnination procedure to be carried out before public beta to avoid a massive influx of questions with these tags**:

1. Go through every question with the [drone](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drone) and [small-drones](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/small-drones) tag
2. Consider the following options:

   - Tag with the correct tags (creating them if need-be)
   - If very low quality, try and salvage the question
   - If it's very hard to salvage the question, deletion can be considered

After this process has happened, we can talk about an alternative [small-drones](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/small-drones) tag for drones weighing less than 250 grams.

Comment: I'm not sure why this isn't an answer to the linked question, especially as it's a straight suggestion. Consider reposting this there, maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The burnination has now been completed!