# Blacklist the [drone] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The [drone](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drone) tag was recently burninated:

- [Burninate the [drone] and [small-drones] tags](https://drones.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101/burninate-the-drone-and-small-drones-tags)

The reason for burnination was:

> These tags are incredibly broad

I heavily agree with this. This tag recently appeared on 2 questions (I’ve now removed the tag from both):

- [My DIY Project - My motors and voltage regulator for water pump does not work at the same time](https://drones.stackexchange.com/posts/1469/revisions)
- [Motor size and Kv advice for ZD550?](https://drones.stackexchange.com/posts/1434/revisions)

Can this tag be blacklisted so we can’t recreate it again?

Comment: This is a great point... how can we do this?

Comment: @ifconfig A CM will need to do it, by tagging as status-review it should get their attention